# symfony move app, vendor,bin folder in private folder

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

In my host i got private folder and web folder. To run php outside the web directory i need to put everything in the private folder. See the picture. App,src, vendor, logs, bin to be in the private folder.

[image]

I realize that the bootstrap app.php and app_dev.php need to point to the private folder

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../private/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../private/app/AppKernel.php';
```

But i cannot run the server:run command and i don't know all the steps when you move all those folders for configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few things to finish your work.
You must change your `composer.json`.

Replace values in your `composer.json` with this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "private/src/",
            "SymfonyStandard\\": "private/app/SymfonyStandard/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "private/vendor"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "private\\app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "private\\web"
    }
}
```

Remove your `vendor` folders and do `composer update`.
To finish, just add `--docroot` at your `server:run` command:

```
app/console server:run --docroot=/home/workspace/...
```

Comment: I have move the composer json to the private directory so i have not need to change anything right?

Comment: I have tested it and it works. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: `composer install` instead of `update` if you don't want to update your vendors